# $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$ for each $x\in [0, 1]$. Then which of the following statement is True?

Tags: real-analysis

$C[0, 1]$ denotes the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence
of functions in $C[0, 1]$ such that $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$ for each $x\in [0, 1]$. Then

which of the following statement is True ?

[image]

I thinks option c will be  true  by uniform convergence theorem

im not sure  about other option
Any/hints solution  will be  appreciated

pliz help  me

thanks u

Comment: a and b are ruled aout by $x\mapsto x^n$.

Comment: I also believe c is true. $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a** and **b** are clearly false since $f$ is not necessarily continuous. **c** is however true. We have $$\int_0^{1-1/n}f_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^{1}f_n(x)\,dx+\int_{1-1/n}^1 f_n(x)\,dx.$$ Since $[0,1]$ is compact and the functions $f_n$ are continuous, they are therefore bounded on the interval and since they converge uniformly, it follows that the sequence of functions is uniformly bounded, i.e. that there exists some number $M$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $n$ and $x$. Thus $$\Bigg|\int_{1-1/n}^1 f_n(x)\,dx\Bigg|\leq\int_{1-1/n}^1 M\,dx=\frac{M}{n}\to 0\text{ as } n\to \infty.$$ Furthermore, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, the validity of **c** follows by the above equality. This also implies that **d** is false.

Comment: Thanks u so much❤️❤️apanpapan